# Proving the order of a group, $G$

Tags: group-theory

> Let $p$ be a prime and let $$G=\left\{\begin{pmatrix}1&a&b\\0&1&c\\0&0&1\end{pmatrix}|\ a,b,c \in \mathbb{Z}_p\right\}$$
>   Show that under matrix multiplication, $G$ is a nonabelian group of order $p^3$.

I can easily show that this a group (by showing associativity, closure, and inverse) and I can easily show that this is nonabelian. I am having trouble showing that $\mid G| = p^3$.

Comment: How many $a's$ are possible for a $a_{12}$ entry?

Comment: There is a distinct element of $G$ for each $(a,b,c)\in\mathbb{Z}_p^3$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the determinant of this matrix is always $1$ no matter what $a,b,c$ you choose and you have $p$ choices for each variable entry, you have $p^3$ choices overall and each of them gives you a distinct element of the group.

The reason that the determinant is always $1$ is because it is upper triangular. Therefore, you don't have to worry about linear dependence of the columns or the rows of your matrix when you choose $a,b,c$.